# unramified implies separable

Tags: algebraic-geometry

Is it true that if one has a unramified dominant morphism $\varphi:X\to Y$ between two schemes $X,Y$ irreducibles, then this morphism is separable? It seems to be very easy but I don't see it anywere. If $X\to Y$ is unramified then for $\xi_X$ and $\xi_Y$ respective generics points then $\xi_X\mapsto \xi_Y$ (dominant) so by non ramification $k(\xi_X)/k(\xi_Y)$ is separable so $k(X)/k(Y)$ is separable.Is it correct?

Comment: It looks correct, yes.